# Como criar um servidor para colocar um site online?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5

Fala pessoal, tudo ok?

Bom sei que minha pergunta do titulo ta um pouco estranha, mas aparente deve ter uma resposta bem simples kkkk

Mas antes vou explicar um pouco da minha situação! Eu e meus amigos estamos tentando "Criar" um site nosso para que possamos jogar um rpgzinho de mesa maroto. E não, não somos pessoas que não tem o que fazer kkkkk. Faz muito tempo que não jogamos algo porque não temos tempo ou interesse, a unica coisa que nos une é o famoso RPG de Mesa, jogamos isso durante um tempão na adolescência.

Sim, isso mesmo! É um pouco complicado fazer vários cálculos matemáticos de dano, status e tbm os atributos do set e arma. Estamos querendo automatizar tudo. Eles deixaram a parte dessa automação para mim, mesmo eu não sabendo muito sobre programação, aprendi bastante coisa em curto espaço de tempo, consegui desenvolver algumas coisas no HTM e jav.

Estou terminando a parte de "Status do personagem" que seria uma das principais e agora me dei conta não sei como vou fazer para colocar tudo isso em servidor ou banco de dados para que eu consiga jogar junto de meus amigos.

Então a minha pergunta é, como eu posso fazer isso? Meio que deixar a minha página "Online", como se tivesse um login para acessar no site e que o usuário daquele login tivesse alguns atributos que seria a folha de personagem.

```css
.body{
}
.body #forma img{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    bottom:1px;
    left:1px;
}
#button1{
margin-top:300px;
}
#button1 button{
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;
    left: 45%;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.botoes img{
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top:2px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
#sts{
    width: 38%;
    height: 65%;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top:18%;
    left:32%;
    border-radius: 58px 58px 58px 58px;
-moz-border-radius: 58px 58px 58px 58px;
-webkit-border-radius: 58px 58px 58px 58px;
border: 0px solid #000000;
opacity: 0.5;
}
#sts h2{
    margin-left:43%;
}
#input1{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:16%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;  
}
#input2{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:16%;
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;  
}
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <div id="forma">
        <img src="https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/prime_world-1920x1080.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="botoes">
    <div id="menu"><img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/fairy-tail-rpg/images/4/48/Parchment.png/revision/latest?cb=20150830172723&path-prefix=pt-br">
        <div id="sts">
            <h2><b>STATUS</b></h2>
            <input id="input1" type="text" placeholder="Nickname">
            <input id="input2"type="input" placeholder="Raça"><br>
            <input id="input2"type="input" placeholder="Classe">
            <input id="input2"type="input" placeholder="Sub-Classe"><br>
            <input id="input2"type="input" placeholder="Título">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Opa beleza?

Então cara, primeiramente pra que você possa "criar" um servidor você teria que ter um investimento muito alto rsrsrsrs. Recomendo fazer o seguinte (a maioria trabalha assim). Ao invés de você montar um servidor, porque você não hospeda seu site em servidores?

Exemplo, temos a Hostgator que para seu caso serve muito bem e não é tão caro o invesimento. Fora isso, vocês vão precisar registrar um domínio via registro.br ou na própria provedora de servidor (Hostgator).

Você tem que pensar no seguinte. Seu site (ou jogo online) são vários arquivos, e você precisa deixar esses arquivos acessíveis, e por esse motivo a necessidade de registrar um domínio, publicá-lo em um serviço de hospedagem e depois disso tudo você poderá acessar seu site.
Hospede aqui: https://www.hostgator.com.br
Registre o domínio aqui: https://registro.br/

Claro que isso você e seus amigos deverão pagar uma mensalidade e anuidade.
Geralmente funciona assim: O Registro de domínio R$ 40,00 (ano) e a mensalidade na hospedagem pra manter seu site no ar (esse preço varia muito com a necessidade, e deve consultar a Hostgator).

Espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida, pois não conheço (e acho que nem existe) outros meios para publicar um site (a não ser que você tenha um servidor próprio).